# sharing variables between running applications in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, dll, sharing

I am developing in C# two simple applications, running in the same local machine without network requirements.

The first application initializes an DLL (Class1) and set a variable. The second application just read it the data which was previously stored. Both applications instanciates the same Class1.

Code:

- DLL (Class1):

  ```
  public class Class1
  {

  private string variableName;

  public string MyProperty
   {
      get { return variableName; }
      set { variableName = value; }
    }

  }
  ```
- Application A:

  ```
  class Program
  {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Class1 class1 = new Class1();

      string localReadVariable = Console.ReadLine();

      class1.MyProperty = localReadVariable;

     }
  }
  ```
- Application B:

  ```
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      ClassLibraryA.Class1 localClass = new ClassLibraryA.Class1();

      string z = localClass.MyProperty;

      Console.WriteLine(z);
  }
  }
  ```

My problem is that I do not know how to read a variable from another thread.

Application B must read the "variableName" set by application B

Thank you

Comment: This might be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360533/how-to-share-data-between-different-threads-in-c-sharp-using-aop

Comment: I hope you are aware of the fact that each program has its own instance of `Class1`!

Comment: Yes!! Thats the problem, both applications create different instances and I dont know how to communicate them in a easy way. I ve heard about WCF, pipes, registy... but I cannot find an esay implementation which I am sure that there is...

@Wimbo I found it also, but As I know so far, that post is communication between threads from the same instance is It? In my case I have different threads from different instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some sort of mechanism to communicate between the applications.

This can be through the registry, files, [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) etc...

If both applications are expected to do write, you need to add synchronization logic to your code.

Comment: I would not like to Use files because the data stored in the variable is a "password"

What about registry? Can you provide an snippet code example for that mechanism?

Comment: @kmxillo - What makes you think that registry usage is safer than files? You can always _encrypt_ the password before writing.

Comment: I would suggest using WCF for inter process communication as you won't have to worry about accessing files nor locking them: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Comment: @Slugart WCF overheads a lot the code.. as you see the purpose is just one variable. I do not need the reason why I have to create a communication across the web when the programs are running locally.

Comment: WCF does not necessarily use 'the web', your local network or even TCP/IP.  You should use the NetNamedPipeBinding and not the HttpBinding.

Comment: @Slugart - No, but even in proc there is quite a large overhead, in particular for such a small amount of data.

Comment: @Slugart - Added CPU and memory usage during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way for Application B to read data created in Application A. Each application has its own address space and thus do not know of the others existence.

But, there are ways to do this!

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439787/how-to-implement-shared-memory-in-net) for one method..

Comment: What happen when the apps run on the same process?

Comment: @kmxillo: Each app runs in its own process, they don't share processes.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used two methods:

1. Use a database table to contain your common data. If you wrap your
   calls to it in transactions then you also protection from
   concurrency issues.
2. Use [PersistentDictionary](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation) to store your data, protected by a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx). You must have some interprocess locking since PersistentDictionary can only be open by one process at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.net Remoting`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example) to communicate between your two application.
Remoting also does not require a network address to communicate.

Comment: Remoting has been deprecated for ages now. WCF has been the mechanism to use for quite a while now.

Comment: Thanks for the update - haven't used remoting since 2.0 and actually used WCF, but didn't know its also the recommended way for IPC now...

Comment: .NET Remoting may be deprecated, but that does not make this answer technically incorrect or anything like that. It is a legit option; just not the best one.