# How to communicate across projects inside one .NET solution?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a .NET Core (UWP solution) application which has 3 different projects (let's call them A, B and C).

A and B are Windows Runtime Components, and C is a simple Class Library.

Projects A and B have a reference to the project C.

I would like to access a class of the project C, whose the instance would be shared between projects A and B.

I thought to a singleton pattern (of course), using the Lazy method of .NET 4

Problem is that the instance is not the same each time A and B projects access the instance. The Lazy method creates a new instance of the class because it seems not to be previously created. I wonder if I can share a singleton between different projects of a solution. I've read that a project is associated to a process, and each process has its own memory space which cannot be shared. Is there a solution to my issue?

**EDIT**:
Here's my implementation of my HubService class:

```
    private static readonly Lazy<HubService> Lazy =
        new Lazy<HubService>(() => new HubService(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    private HubService()
    {
        _asyncQueue = new AsyncQueue<Guid>();
    }

    public static HubService Instance => Lazy.Value;
```

Also, is it possible to share a singleton across different assemblies using tools like Castle Windsor, Ninject, Autofac or Unity?

Comment: We need to see your implementation of the singleton, as well as the way you use it in both A and B.

Comment: It's not the same instance, so you can't. Your project C assembly is loaded into A and B separately, and it doesn't just magically share memory between 2 processes

Comment: Do a static sealed singleton implementation of your class initialization. This will prevent multiple threads accessing your lazy initialization.

Comment: @Glubus I've edited my question

Comment: @LibertyLocked Yeah that's what I'm thinking about. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: You might also want to do a lock. the section at the bottom should help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: @Maertin Lazy<T> is a better implementation of a thread-safe singleton. No need to use lock I think when using Lazy

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803432/sharing-variables-between-running-applications-in-c-sharp

Comment: Consider using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) for inter process communication.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ I think WCF is overkill here, especially for a UWP app. What about Autofac or any other DI framework? Is it possible to share a singleton across different assemblies using tools like Castle Windsor, Ninject, Autofac or Unity?

Comment: You could use an out of process cache to store objects/data. AppFabric for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton class won't work here - every process will has its own memory and so its own singleton.

AFAIK in *UWP* for inter process (between background tasks and main UI, apart from audio task) communication you will need some kind of a broker. For short synchronization you may think of using *LocalSettings*, for more complicated scenarios maybe a file/database in *LocalFolder*. If you decide to use a file you will need to synchronize processes, for this purpose you have objects like *Mutex* nad *WaitHandles*.