# Background Task UWP - Pass Object with Data

Tags: object, win-universal-app, windows-10, isolatedstorage, background-task

I need to pass an object with some information to consume in my Background Task. I try to search in web but not found any solution. It is possible?

One workarround is save information what I need to pass in isolated storage in my MainProjet and in my BackgroundTask project consume information saved before. But this solution is not beautiful to use.

Someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apart from media player which has an ability to communicate with UI, the answer will be [similar as to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35943376/2681948) - you will have to use some kind of a broker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SendMessageToBackground method

```
  var message = new ValueSet();
                    message.Add("key",value);
                    BackgroundMediaPlayer.SendMessageToBackground(message);
```

In background task listen to this method

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
   {
   BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromForeground += BackgroundMediaPlayer_MessageReceivedFromForeground;
    }

  private void BackgroundMediaPlayer_MessageReceivedFromForeground(object sender, MediaPlayerDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string key in e.Data.Keys)
            {
                switch (key.ToLower())
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But this will work only with MediaPlayer, other BTasks will need some kind of a broker.

Comment: @archana, my Background task only do update live tile. Is not related witd media player. Thanks