# VB - how to access data from a class running on another thread (serial object)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port, invokerequired

I am writing a class called Field which uses a serial object to get some values from an Arduino. I have an event being raised by the class (when data is received from the serial port, more or less) and when that happens I need to retrieve data from this class. The code below works, but doesn't seem to do so in the way I need it to. My knowledge of just how threading works is little to none, I just know that the serial port object runs in its own thread which makes working with it a massive pain.

```
Private Sub Field_eScore() Handles Field.eScore

    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(Sub() lbl_COM_data.Text = Field.GetComData())
    Else
        lbl_COM_data.Text = Field.GetComData()
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there a way to easily access data operating in this other thread that doesn't involve having these “InvokeRequired” If-Then conditionals? Some more information on just how threading works in this case would be awesome too.

Comment: Heres propably the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360533/how-to-share-data-between-different-threads-in-c-sharp-using-aop
and here are some good informations about threading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26148/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-1-of-n

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I like the document about threading, that's a cool set. Unfortunately the other stackoverflow reference isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: You shouldn't replicate code like that. The Invoke could call itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvokeRequired` is required because the UI can only be modified by the thread that created the controls (normally the main thread).

To "avoid" it, design your code to separate the responsibilities -- keep UI modification in a different layer from code dealing with serial port.

You'll still need to check if `InvokeRequired` in some places -- where you do interface your backend with the UI -- but it should be only in one "layer".