# thread method parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hello I create 3 threads but I need that they use one array list in common to insert data , my question is that I create a thread like this `Thread t = new Thread(doThread);` but if you see do thread it’s a method without parameters but i want to pass the array list mentioned before.
It´s possible ?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but some good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360533/how-to-share-data-between-different-threads-in-c-sharp-using-aop

Comment: in fact what i really need to pass its a textbox, the arraylist and some strings.

Comment: be careful, ArrayLists are not thread safe.

Comment: `ArrayList` is also obsolete. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: `List<T>` is also obsolete when working with multithreading, use something from the `System.Colections.Concurrent` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ParameterizedThreadStart` Delegate

For example,

```
ArrayList theList = new ArrayList(); 
Thread t = new Thread(doThread);
t.Start(theList);
```

This will work as long as your delegate, `doThread`, has a matching signature of:

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(
    Object obj
)
```

More information about the `ParameterizedStart` delegate can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx).

Edit - just read that you will be needing more than an `ArrayList`. Keep in mind that while it only accepts one parameter, you can create your own `Object` as a wrapper for everything that you need to send to the method.

```
public class SendDataExample
{
   public ArrayList myList { get; set; }
   public string myString { get; set; }
}
```

You could then use the `Object` in your delegate like this:

```
public void doThread(object data)
{
    var sendDataExample = (SendDataExample)data;
    ArrayList myList = sendDataExample.myList;
    string myString = sendDataExample.myString;
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok sounds great create the object, how use it in the method can you wirte a little example. Please